# Why Activity Monitor shows different memory usage of Java then Java running itself?

Tags: java, memory

So I have this code:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        integers.ensureCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE/5);
        System.out.println(runtime.totalMemory()/1000000);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Which prints out something around 1975 for me.

But at the same time I am watching the Activity Monitor in Mac Os and it says Java process is using 1.62Gib

Why the difference?

Comment: What does `totalMemory` return? What does the Activity Monitor show, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Your programm only shows the memory of the JVM of YOUR little programm. Other programms use their own JVM, with their own memory. Only special native libraries like OpenCL are not full visualized.

For memory analyse please use the Java VisualVM (JDK 1.7 or higher in ./bin (installation folder of java) or http://visualvm.java.net/ ).
There is a concrete list of running JVMs and their memory-usage. You can do a Heap dump and look, what how much memory is used by what object.